# How to get session from cxf out interceptor

Tags: java, spring, session, cxf

I have a cxf "in interceptor" bound to Receive phase that store data into session.

**MyCxfInInterceptor (In interceptor)**

```
public class MyCxfInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    public MyCxfInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        HttpServletRequest request (HttpServletRequest)message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        session.setAttribute("foo","bar");
    }
}
```

**MyCxfOutInterceptor (Out interceptor)**

```
public class MyCxfOutInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
      public MyCxfOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.SEND);
      }


      public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        //TODO Retrieve data from session.
      }
    }
```

I want to retrieve theses data into my "out interceptor". How can i do it ?

I don't know how to retrieve session from HttpServletResponse. Maybe the session is not available anymore. Is there any other way to store & retrieve data?

Spring could be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Exchange`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Exchange.html), to exchange the data between in and out interceptor

**In interceptor**

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
  message.getExchange().put("foo","bar");
}
```

**Out interceptor**

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
  Object obj = message.getExchange().get("foo");
 }
```